# How to publish page that can't be detected by search engines?

Tags: admin, google-search, search-engines

I like to publish drafts in my 'Uncategorized' category.  This category is not linked anywhere on my site.  It's great for allowing contributors to an article to read the draft before it is made public.  The problem is that after just 2 or 3 days, search engines begin picking up the draft and people start posting comments.

I don't want to password protect the draft.  Is there some way to hide it from search engines while it is in the 'Uncategorized' category?

Comment: Keep in mind that not all search engines honor a noindex request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this on your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'no_robots_on_uncategorized_posts');
function no_robots_on_uncategorized_posts() {

    if(in_category('uncategorized')) {
        wp_no_robots();
    }

}
```

This will output the following line of code on the header of your 'uncategorized' posts:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
```

What this means is that even though search engines will see the page, they will be told to ignore it and don't show it on their results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your `robots.txt`?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /category/uncategorized/*
```

Since there is no link anywhere in your blog, you should only be concerned by the category archives; in this way search engines should not crawl those parts of your site.
Is there any other way that your drafts are accessible? You might consider also modifying the `category-uncategorized.php` template file, so that those posts are in no way accessible without having a direct link.

Comment: Thanks.  I display only a customized archive.  What kind of modification would category-uncategorized.php need?  Do you have some kind of example?

Comment: Well, to make it inaccessible you could just do something as simple as `wp_die("We are sorry, but this category is not accessible")`, or you could make a conditional which makes the loop available only if the `user_role` is **contributor**. You have different solutions, but if you are worried only of search engines and not users trying to access that archive by manually typing the URL, the first `robots.txt` solution should do.